# Fetch data from Laravel query builder with with elquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have two tables with many-to-many relationships and pivot table

Table 1: tours | id | name | country_id |
Table 2: countries | id | name |
Piviot table: country_tour | id | country_id | tour_id|

Model 1
Tour.php

```
   public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country');
}
```

Model 2
Country.php

```
    public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
}
```

How can fetch data with query builder. I'm trying this

```
$featured = DB::table('tours')->where('country', 'Croatia')->get();
```

and i'm getting error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tours` where `country` = Croatia)
```

Comment: What do you mean by category here.. What do you want at the end?

Comment: it looks like you are querying wrong column, `tour` table don't have any `category` column. And why you have a `country_id` column in tour table, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Yes, indeed I had made mistake in the query. Now I have made the correction, but still getting the error. How do I fetch the data from pivot table ? Does elequent model helps to fetech the data ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a many-to-many relationship as I see. Many-to-many would be `hasAndBelongsToMany` not `belongsToMany`. But the problem with your query is different. Your `tours` tables does not have an existing `category` column. By the way you could use `\App\Tour::where()` instead of `DB::table('tours')->where()`. That's what model classes are for.

Answer (score 0):

To utilize eloquent's model relationships, you need to use the model itself and not a DB query:

```
$croatia = App\Country::whereName('Croatia')->first();
$toursInCroatia = $croatia->Tours;
```